# Where to get an aggregate view of ratings, reviews and ranking for WP7 apps?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

What service or tool are you using to track your Windows Phone 7 apps on the marketplace (ranking over time, reviews across all markets)? This is probably not the best forum to ask this question. However since some people on must be developing apps for WP, I am sure someone knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FromConceptToCodeIn6HoursShippingMyFirstWindowsPhoneApp.aspx):

http://wp7reviews.tomverhoeff.com/

http://www.wpdashboard.net/ (not working)

I think this is the new one: http://wpdwebsite.apphb.com/ - The link to "get it now" on that page doesn't work, maybe it's down right now.  If it's down later, I'll update this.

Comment: Thanks! The second link doesn't work.

Comment: WPD, looks promising, I haven't used it for a while.  I use the first one all the time.